# I need to make a input text field for other users to put their links? How do I do that using a api?

Tags: qr-code, api-design

So I need the users to enter in the field but I don't know and when users enter their links using the field it will automatically generate a QR code in png format.

Here is the code:

After the "/" is the linked part that's how the QR code is generated try it for yourself. But I need to make it so that users enter in their links or words after the third "/" then the qr code is automatically generated does anybody know how to do that? And the .X-UA-Compatible needs to always stay there.

```css
body {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.qrcode {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <img class="qrcode" src="https://qr.eletto.dev/www.amazon.X-UA-Compatible"/> 
    
</body>
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? How is this related to designing an API?

Answer (score 0):

### HTML

```
    <main>
      <input type="url" name="url" id="url" />
      <img src="https://qr.eletto.dev/https://qr.eletto.dev" alt="" />
    </main>
```

### JS

```
const url = document.querySelector("#url");
const img = document.querySelector("img");
url.addEventListener("change", () => {
  img.src = `https://qr.eletto.dev/${url.value}.X-UA-Compatible`;
});
```